# Find max abs of subtraction between lists in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list like this:

```
l = [[8,7,6], [9,9,9], [4,5,9], [1,5,1]]
```

and I would like to find the max value of the subtraction of elements between 2 consecutive lists. 
Example:

Between `[9,9,9]` and `[8,7,6]` -> max of `[1,2,3]` -> 3

Between `[4,5,9]` and `[9,9,9]` -> max of `[5,4,0]` -> 5

Between `[1,5,1]` and `[4,5,9]` -> max of `[3,0,8]` -> 8

And then I would like to have a list with `[3,5,8]`
Since I the code has to be compatible with the version 1.6.1 of `numpy`, I am doing in this way:

```
new_l = []
for index, i in enumerate(l):
    if index < len(l)-1:
        t = []
        for jndex, j in enumerate(i):
            t.append(l[index +1][jndex] - l[index][jndex])

    new_l.append(max([abs(number) for number in t]))
new_l = new_l[:-1]
```

Is there a better way? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to use NumPy : `np.abs(np.diff(l,axis=0)).max(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular Python, you can use a list comprehension with `zip` twice:

```
L = [[8,7,6], [9,9,9], [4,5,9], [1,5,1]]

res = [max(abs(i-j) for i, j in zip(*values)) for values in zip(L, L[1:])]

[3, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following nested comprehension will work:

```
l = [[8,7,6], [9,9,9], [4,5,9], [1,5,1]]

[max(map(abs, (x-y for x, y in zip(a, b)))) for a, b in zip(l, l[1:])]
# [3, 5, 8]
```

`zip(l, l[1:])` produces pairs of adjacent lists that are then zipped again to retrieve the pairwise differences.

Answer (score 1):

As per [@Divakar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776720/find-max-abs-of-subtraction-between-lists-in-a-list/52776795#comment92475206_52776720), this is the standard NumPy solution:

```
res = np.abs(np.diff(L, axis=0)).max(1)
```

For large arrays you may see a significant performance improvement via `numba`. Both versions are more efficient than the non-vectorised Python list comprehension.

```
from numba import njit

L = np.array([[8,7,6], [9,9,9], [4,5,9], [1,5,1]] * 10**6)

@njit
def differ(A):
    res = np.zeros(A.shape[0]-1)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            res[i] = max(res[i], abs(A[i+1, j] - A[i, j]))
    return res

assert np.array_equal(np.abs(np.diff(L, axis=0)).max(1), differ(L))

%timeit np.abs(np.diff(L, axis=0)).max(1)  # 161 ms per loop
%timeit differ(L)                          # 53.7 ms per loop
%timeit [max(abs(i-j) for i, j in zip(*v)) for v in zip(L, L[1:])]  # 22.5 s per loop
```